# What will $W$ converge to?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

$$W=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})(Y_i-\bar{Y})}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\bar{Y})^2}}$$

Good morning all. I am supposed to implement "the appropriate statistical theorems or methods" to answer what $W$ will converge to as the sample size $n$ approaches infinity.

At the top of my head, I saw the word converge and the sample size approaching infinity and thought of plim and the law of large numbers (LLN). I think I have to divide everything by n to obtain the sample average, and then I can say that it will converge to its expected value?

I believe the denominator will converge to the population variance (sigma squared), but what about the top?

Really hope for some insights.

Comment: Looks like covariance, with an unbalanced parenthesis.

Comment: whoops. forgot about that. ill edit it now.

Comment: I added W. Take a look.

Comment: Thanks Marty for the addition

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134910/show-that-the-sample-covariance-converges-in-probability-to-the-covx-y